# A question about a notation

Tags: matrices, notation

Let $A$ be a non-singular square matrix. Which of the following notations is correct? 
$${A^2}^{-1} \qquad \text{or} \qquad A^{-2}$$

Comment: both are correct. second one is more common.

Comment: The notation on the left is a little ambiguous. If you're intending the two notations to represent the same thing, it should be $(A^2)^{-1}$. What you've written is generally interpreted as $A^{(2^{-1})}$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski the Mathjax used was {A^2}^{-1}, which indicates OP meant the first case

Comment: Good point. I was aware that the OP intended the first case. I was just try Bing to point out that using parentheses will avoid confusion in the future. For example, when MathJax is not involved.

Comment: Exeuse me, what is the meaning of "OP"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the first one is interpreted as $(A^2)^{-1}$. Note that $A^{-2}$ is *defined* as $(A^{-1})^2$. Hence, if you want to interpret the two as meaning the same thing you have to think about it:

**Exercise:** Determine whether or not $(A^2)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^2$ for all non-singular square matrix $A$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Because, $A^2(A^{-1})^2=AAA^{-1}A^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I_n$. So $(A^{-1})^2$ is the inverse of $A$, i.e. $(A^2)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^2$.

Comment: @DavidMayar Good!